# GCP Firebase connection to compute engine VM

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcp-vpc-firewall

this is my current setup:

1. a flutter application hosted and deployed on firebase in eu (multiple regions in European Union)
2. a compute engine VM deployed in asia-northeast1-b
3. on the VM machine I have a websocket server running

From my flutter application on firebase I want to connect to my websocket server on the compute engine machine and consume the messages.

In my local environment everything is working fine, but I cannot sort out the connection between the flutter app on firebase and the VM on compute engine.

Is there any guide to achieve this scenarios?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If the answer below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark or just [upvote it if was useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Sneaky Hector Martinez :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not a guide per se.

You could deploy an API -that you should develop- to a [Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-compute-engine-docker), and consume said API in the flutter app hosted in Firebase.